# Use Perl to extract fields from a large text file using column numbers from another file

Tags: bash, perl, shell, text-files, large-files

I have two files

- A text file with a list of numbers, e.g.

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  5
  7
  6
  ```

  each number is on a different line, and the row number corresponds to a column number in the second file.
- A large text file with ~150,000 columns. I need to extract only the columns listed in the first file.

I would prefer to do this command-line-style so I came up with this

```
for i in columns.txt do 

perl -lane 'print $F[i]' final.txt > output.txt
```

I want to do something like this, but without combining Bash and script Perl

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_col; $i++) {          # for each line in the column file 1
    my $column = $columns[$i];               # extract the number from the line
    perl -lane 'print $F[$column]' final.txt > output.txt; # and cut that column from file #2 into output file
}
```

How to do this without combining a Perl script and Bash?

I am new to scripting so explanations would be great as well as code help.

final looks like this but with dimensions 106713 x 119,962

6665 AA AG TG CC GG GT TA TT

6667 AT TC AT CG GA GA TC AA

6668 AC TC TT CA GT GA TC CG

6669 AG AC AA CT GG GA TC CA

6670 AA AT AG AC GG GA TC AA

ID 2 2 1 1 1 6 6 1                                        #this single row is the columns.txt file

ID rs3755048 rs2276637 rs1043502 rs879089 rs647812 rs2076310 c6_pos32913147 rs1051741

ID 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

ID 219793146 219797929 20850335 20841103 20866804 33274012 32913147 224098852

Comment: How many lines are there in this 150,000-column file?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your file data at all. Is all of that in a single file? I thought each number was on a different line in `columns.txt`? Your final sentence doesn't seem to relate to the rest of the question at all. Please explain.

Comment: Echoing @Borodin here. Please show the output of `head columns.txt` as well as `head data-file | cut -b-80`. Copy and paste directly from the output, don't type from memory. You seem to be working with gene data. Are you sure [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page) can't help?

Comment: @ Borodin the columns.txt file is just a copy of parts of a single line in final.txt.  Basically i want to sort final.txt based on the criteria i select for that one row.  So far it works for non-numerical selection but as soon as i try so separate for 1 or 5 the columns shift in selection.

Comment: which i just found as an error in my original sort algorithm :/ The selection is working minus speed issues so I guess this is resolved. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace one-liner with script equivalent, that would be:

```
# local $/ = "\n";
open my $fh, "<", "final.txt" or die $!;
open my $out, ">", "output.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split ' ', $_;
  print $out "$F[$column]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want, but it may be slow. If it is too slow to be useful then come back and we can talk about optimising it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @columns = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'columns.txt';
  local $/;
  <$fh> =~ /\d+/g;
};

my @indices = map { $_ - 1 } sort { $a <=> $b } @columns;

open my $fh, '<', 'final.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split ' ', $_, $indices[-1] + 2;
  print join(' ', @fields[@indices]), "\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: this works great on my small test file but when working with the actual files its quite slow and I need to do this 23 different times on a 65 MB file with 100,000 row x 200,000 column data.... how can it be sped up?

Comment: actually, it seems like its not grabbing the columns correctly

Comment: @roserose: It is splitting the lines on whitespace. What exactly is wrong with the columns it is selecting?

Comment: @roserose: Please will you show several lines of `final.txt` (add to your question or post it on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com))? Are the fields in always in the same columns? Are the 23 separate runs just different selections of columns in `columns.txt`? If so then you can run all 23 at once. Would that help?

Comment: the column selections seem to get shifted after awhile in my large file.  Small test files seem to select them ok.  its just 23 different selections criteria in the column.txt

Comment: @roserose: Okay I can change it so that you can create 23 `columns.txt` files and process them all at once. It won't be much slower than processing just one.

Comment: @roserose: The lines from `final.txt` that are being selected wrongly must have spaces in one of the fields. Please check. Are the fields always two letters?

Answer (score 0):

use a single perl one-liner with a condition on $ARGV change, something like:

```
perl -lane 'if ($fh ne $ARGV){$fh=$ARGV;$++}push @cols, $_ if $i<2;if ($i>1){foreach(@cols){print $F[$_]})}' ONE TWO
```